# HTML5 GeoLocation Address Form Filler Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to coding in general.

I keep getting the

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error and I have no idea what's wrong.

```
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.onload = function() {

  //if we make a successful request and it returns an address
  if(this.status==200 && JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).contents.results.length > 0){
    //get formatted address from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding
    var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).contents.results[0].formatted_address;
    putInDom(result);
  } else {
    //send some general error
    info.innerHTML = "Could not find your location.";
  }

}
```

Here's where I get the zip file from. I appreciate all helps. Thank you.
http://techslides.com/html5-geolocation-address-form-filler

Comment: try to print/alert the `xhr.responseText` before `if` condition and see what response you are getting.

Comment: This is the response when I print xhr.responseText. Down below. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your response is HTML, not JSON. Therefore `JSON.parse` is throwing a `SyntaxError` on the `<` token.

Comment: It's not a JSON response so you can't parse it as JSON. Without seeing the full response I can't tell you how to parse or use it.

Comment: This is the response when I print xhr.responseText. I'm so sorry, I'm really new.

Comment: Aha, there we are. It *is* JSON, but you have some PHP notices breaking the response. Ideally you would fix those, but as they're only notices they're not critical. Add `error_reporting(0);` to the top of `ba-simple-proxy.php` to disable those.